# Is it possible to configure different power management settings for plugged\unplugged?

Tags: power

In windows and Ubuntu (and other distro's) it's possible to assign different power management settings for when on battery power vs plugged.

For example, I'd like the PC to sleep when i close the lid on battery power, but do nothing if I'm connected to a charger.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

The settings you are asking for show up in the Power menu but just don't seem to do anything for me.
I use TLP for power management.